# Application Bar scrolls up the Webbrowser view in Windows phone App

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8, application-bar

I have been working on a windows phone 8 app. I have given complete space of my layout to a WebBrowser element which renders my mobile site's pages.

Those pages has:
-A **fixed header** at the top.
-A **fixed text box** for replies and search at the bottom
-And a **scrollable region in between**.

I have also provided my app with an Application Bar which provides buttons for some quick links. Application Bar comes and goes depending on the page user is.

Now the problem is:
- When Application Bar comes up, my **whole pages scrolls up and the fixed header goes out of view**. without Application Bar things are fine.

Somebody else facing the same problem?
Are there any workarounds for this?

**NOTE** - I tried reserving some space for the application bar and giving rest of the space to WebBrowser, but that also doesn't help. And strange thing is, things are working fine on emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the platform does the same thing that happens when the SIP shows up - that would mean the root visual element has a `RenderTransform`/`TransformGroup`/`TranslateTransform` that gets updated when some OS component like the app bar shows up. Check Vinoth's answer to this question here:

[Scrollable form control in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064034/scrollable-form-control-in-windows-phone-8/23066147#23066147)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for the page to scroll up (i.e. title disappears) when application bar opens.  you can not do much about that.

If your need is to have whole webpage visible including the title when the application bar is in view, then you need to reduce the height of web browser so it fit into a smaller window.